# Why I cannot select from some selected results?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am a bit new to TSQL programming. I am using MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Why the following query doesn't work? I thought a select query just return a bunch of records and I should still be able to select from those records.

```
select * from
(
select * from dbo.[sometable]
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from
(
select * from dbo.[sometable]
) as X
```

You always need to create alias if using FROM subquery even if later on you're not using this alias that's just how the thing works.

Answer (score 3):

i want to select all the records from sometable then this should be enough

```
select * from dbo.[sometable]
```

However, if you want to filter your records of one table based on values from some other table then you can use nested queries like

```
select * from table1 where id in (select id from table2)
```

or you can use joins like

```
select * from table1 t
join table2 t2 on t.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM dbo.[sometable]
    )
AS [NAME]
```

You need to include an alias for the sub query to be referenced by the outer query